# Colour Formatting every other row

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

I was able to find two codes on stack overflow, but not get it to give one light grey formatted row, followed by white row, help would be appreciated, tried both codes

```
Sub Colour(rng As Range, firstColor As Long, secondColor As Long)
    rng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    rng.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=MOD(ROW(),2)=0"
    rng.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = firstColor
    rng.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=MOD(ROW(),2)<>0"
    rng.FormatConditions(2).Interior.Color = secondColor
End Sub
'Usage:
'
Sub ColourFormatting()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim firstColor As Long
    Dim secondColor As Long

    Set rng = Range("A1:E10")
    firstColor = Pattern = xlSolid: PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic: ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1: TintAndShade = -0.149998474074526: PatternTintAndShade = 0
    secondColor = TintAndShade = 0: PatternTintAndShade = 0
'
    Call Colour(rng, firstColor, secondColor)
End Sub

Sub ShadeEveryOtherRow()
    Dim Counter As Integer

    'For every row in the current selection...
    For Counter = 1 To Range("A1:E30").Rows.Count
        'If the row is an odd number (within the selection)...
        If Counter Mod 2 = 1 Then
            'Set the pattern to xlGray16.
            Range("A1:E30").Rows(Counter).Interior.Pattern = xlSolid: PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic: ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1: TintAndShade = -0.149998474074526: PatternTintAndShade = 0

        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Really confused. Are you trying to add a different conditional formatting or just regular formatting to alternating rows? If it is just formatting what errors are you getting on the "ShadeEveryOtherRow" sub? This one seems like it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need VBA for this - you can use conditional formatting with a formula:

```
=MOD(ROW(),2)=1
```

and set the format to light grey. Do this for the first row and then copy that row across the area as **formats** (paste special).

Your code however uses the wrong delimiter in the parameters, colon in VBA means new line, so your statement

```
Range("A1:E30").Rows(Counter).Interior.Pattern = xlSolid: PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
```

Is the same as

```
Range("A1:E30").Rows(Counter).Interior.Pattern = xlSolid 
PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
```

And I assume VBA is using your latest selection for the second line.

Try:

```
Range("A1:E30").Rows(Counter).Interior.Pattern = xlSolid, PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
```

etc

Comment: I have thirty tables, and I am keen to add this to my code, so I am looking for VBA element

Comment: @user3287522 I guess this comes down to how often you need to do this - If it's a once only then it might just be faster to copy/paste the formats across the 30 tables.

Another option would be to copy the format over one table, and then make a VBA sub that copy and pastes the formats over the applicable tables, rather than actually setting the formats using the code

Comment: I agree with you mate, but I have to do various reports on a weekly basis, so this part would be a lot easier, as I have created a dynamic range, I just need to add this into the code, if I get the above to work, as at the mo, it just colours my whole tables in black.

Comment: @user3287522 To be honest I recommended going the conditional formatting route without even looking at your code - but if your heart is set on fixing up your code, the issue is the delimiter in your parameters. The colon in VBA means new line, try using a comma instead. Added an example to my answer

Comment: Hi everyone, I was able to record a macro with a sample range using the conditional formatting element. I than edited my sample range and applied it to all my tables, by making the range dynamic and using union, this solved my problem.